# Can I pass a FilePicker a custom source using their API

Tags: filepicker.io

Essentially I'm trying to see if I can use file picker to manage user assets.

With they accelerate bundle you can specify a custom s3 source, but only on their dashboard.
I want users to pick and store to their own folders ( which appears to be possible )
but then also be able to re-use those files they have already picked and stored using filepicker.

Is this possible? by reading through the doc it appears not.

Answer (score 0):

Such a feature is not available so far.
I think the only solution here would be to create a database with user filepicker filelinks.